# How to interrupt an user-space app from a Kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a device driver that receives interrupts from hardware. (32 IRQs using MSI)
From the driver, I'd like to signal/interrupt the application that opened the device file that an event occured.

I might be able to use signal but I think it's not really reliable and too slow. Moreover, only 2 SIGUSR are available.

I'd like to avoid adding overhead.

I'd like to avoid them because:

- signal: not enough reliable and high latency
- netlink: high latency, asynchronous and may loose packets
- polling/read/ioctl: need to use a `pthread` and an infinity loop

Currently, I exchange data using ioctl/read/write syscalls.read/write syscalls.

What is the best practice to interrupt/signal an event to an user-space application from a kernel driver?

The method should support many interrupts/signals without loosing any of them, it has to be reliable and fast.

Basically, I'd like to use my user-space app as bottom half of the interrupts I receive in the driver.
The device file is opened by a unique app.

Comment: you say "polling/read/ioctl: need to use a pthread and an infinity loop", but I guess you already have a loop somewhere, so why would you need to add one more? That said, there are no user land interrupts (other than signals) thus you'll need some process context to be woken up, IMHO

Comment: mmh true, I have seen only one example doing that and it was IOCTL calls in  a `while(1)` loop in a separate `pthread`. It takes 100% of CPU all the time since it's continuously polling through ioctl. After having read a bit, I figured out it might be possible to make sleep poll/select syscalls and wake them up at the interrupt.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: you may look at libaio that performs asynchonous io from user land; here some examples, https://github.com/littledan/linux-aio ; for the kernel part browse https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/um/os-Linux/aio.c#L41
basically, the user land waits on a syscall (usually a custom ioctl) and shares a some pages with the kernel. When data is available, the kernel update the shared memory and release the process.

Comment: Thank you OznOg! It should give me a good idea how to implement it.

Comment: Do you know if that is what a NIC driver uses to say to the app that a new packet is available? I'd just like to know if AIO is really what's commonly used and is as good as others.

Comment: That means if I have N MSI irqs, I need N user threads that sleep/wait for the specific ioctl to be processed/awaken (ie new packet came for that irq).

Comment: this is not mandatory, you could, for example, have the kernel fill a structure passed to the ioctl to tell which kind of operation is done. Nevertheless, having multiple thread could (maybe) give better perfs on a multicore machine as you could take advantage of all cores.